# How to retrieve data from Firebase without subscription and nested Observables?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have `Observable<User>` inside another `Observable<Params[]>`, so I have to use nested `Observable.subscribes`.

Is it possible to avoid this situation and retrieve my single User data from Firebase without subscription? I use AngularFire 5.

My Component code:

```
  export class UserAddEditComponent implements OnInit {

  userForm: FormGroup;
  userId: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      if (params['id']) {
        this.userId = params['id'];
        this.usersService.getUser(this.userId).subscribe((user) => {
          this.initForm(user);
        });
      } else {
        this.initForm();
      }
    });
  }
```

P.s. `getUser()` method from `UsersService` returns `Observable<User>`:

```
  getUser (id: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.firebase.doc<User>(`users/${id}`).valueChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use switchMap to wait for the user value

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.pipe(
    map(params => params['id']),
    switchMap(id => {
      // if there was an id we get the user, or else we return an observable with a value of null
      if (id) {
        return this.usersService.getUser(this.userId))
      }
      return Observable.of(null);
  )
  .subscribe((user?: User) => {
    // the user value will be either a user or null
    this.initForm(user);
  });
}
```